# Div containing a registration form disappears after I click submit.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

To make it more clear. On my home page which is index.php I have a button called Register which fires a Jquery script. The script is ment to show the div (which has display:none) containing the registration form on top of the home page. All of this works perfectly.
What am I trying to do is to show some text in this div after the user clicks on the submit button. Currently when I try to do this, after I press the submit button the div gets modified but it disappears and I have to click on the Register button again to see the changes. How can I stop this?

There is the code containing the script and the Register button.

```
    <?php
  include 'register.php';
  include 'login.php';
  include_once 'config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#show').click(function () {
              $('#transparencyL').show();
              $('#frontlayer').show();
          });

          $('#hideL').click(function (e) {
              $('#transparencyL').hide();
              $('#frontlayer').hide();
          });

          $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
              var container = $('#frontlayer');
              var container2 = $('#transparencyL');
              if (!container.is(e.target)               // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                 && container.has(e.target).length === 0)  // ... nor a descendant of the container
              {
                  container.hide();
                  container2.hide();
              }
          });
          $('#registerB').click(function () {
              $('#transparencyR').show();
              $('#registerlayer').show();
          });
          $('#hideR').click(function (e) {
              $('#transparencyR').hide();
              $('#registerlayer').hide();
          });
          $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
              var container3 = $('#registerlayer');
              var container4 = $('#transparencyR');
              if (!container3.is(e.target)
                 && container3.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                  container3.hide();
                  container4.hide();
              }
          });
          /*
          * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
          */
        jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

            }, 'xml');

        });
      });
  </script>
<title>LoveFootball</title>
</head>
<body>       
<div id="topbar">
  <?php if( !(isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) ) { ?>
  <a id="show" href="#">Login</a> 
  <a id="registerB" href="#">Register</a>
  <?php 
} else {
  $usr = new Users;
  $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

  if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
    echo "Welcome"; 
  } else {
    echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
  }
}
?>
```

And this is the code with the div that contains the registration form.

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>LoveFootball</title>
 </head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#laba').click(function () {
              $('#transparencyR').show();
              $('#registerlayer').show();
          });
  };
  </script>
 <body>
<div id="transparencyR" style="display: none;" onclick="return false;"></div>
<div id="registerlayer" style="display: none;">
  <div id="register">
    <p>Register with us now!</p>
    <form class="registerForm" action="#" method="post">
      <table class="registerForm">
        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="usn" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="email" size="31" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" id="passwd" maxlength="30" required name="password" size="31" /></td>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirn Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" id="conpasswd" maxlength="30" required name="conpassword" size="31" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Country:</td>
          <td><select name="country" required>
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
</select></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Date of Birth:</td>
         <td>
           <input type="date" id="conpasswd" maxlength="30" required name="birthDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <?php if( !(isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) ) { ?>
      <input type="submit" style="float: left;" value="Register" name="register" id="laba">
      <?php 
} else {
  $usr = new Users;
  $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

  if( $_POST['password'] == $_POST['conpassword'] ) {
    ?> <p>Registration complete. You are awesome!</p>
    <?php 
  } else {
    ?> <p>Password and confirmed password do not match.Bro pls..</p>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
    </form>
  <input type="button" id="hideR" value="Close">
  </div>
</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I tried to make this work by using the php code from the bottom of the code but as I said, when I click on the submit button the div disappears.

Comment: Do you show the additional text in the div when the page has POSTed?

Comment: Yes, the text appears in the div after I click the submit button but the div itself disappears and in order to see the change you have to click on the Register button again(to show the div containing the registration form).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing input type to "button" instead of "submit" for your register button?

Comment: I tried it right now and after I changed it doesn't do anything.

Comment: My thought was that submit would refresh the page and cause the div to act up.

Comment: I'm new with this kind of stuff but I think it was to be submit in order for my class to take the information out of the form and post it into the database.

Comment: True, another way to do would be to use $.ajax() - would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
      $('#laba').click(function () {
          $('#transparencyR').show();
          $('#registerlayer').show();
      });
```

to this:

```
      $('#laba').click(function () {
          $('#transparencyR').show();
          $('#registerlayer').show();
      });
      <?php if( (isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) ) { ?>
      jQuery('#laba').trigger('click');
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thx for your replay but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: Are you using AJAX to post the data?

Try setting it to
        <?php if( !(isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) ) { ?>
based on your code it might work.

Comment: No, I'm using PHP. I have a class Users that contains the login/registration and store functions.

Comment: Can you try my changed code? I misread some of the JS. :D

If it doesn't work try adding ! in front of (isset( $_POST['register'] ) )

Comment: Tried it, still the same problem.

Comment: Which page are your trying the changes on?

Comment: Well this is happening on my home page a.k.a index.php. But on this page I have a header which is intended to display the top bar and manu on all the pages.That's where I have the scrips for the login and register button. So you could say that the div appears on the header page.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a live demo?

Comment: I have quite a lot of files and I'm also working locally. I don't know if there is any site or tool where I can share that.

Comment: What happens when you are on the page (after POSTing) and you open the browser console and type in this:

jQuery('#laba').trigger('click');

Comment: I get this:Object { context: HTMLDocument → index.php, selector: "#laba" }

Comment: But does it show you the hidden div with the required information?